# Find the domain of the function $f(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+9}}$

Tags: functions

For some reason I can't find domain to this function, but it is pretty clear that it's (ALL X)
$$f(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+9}}$$

I can say that: $$\space x^2+9 > 0\space$$
$$x^2 > -9$$
$$x = \pm \sqrt{-9}$$
I don't get it..

Comment: Your instincts are correct. The only restriction is if what's under the radical sign is negative or $0$ but $x^2 + 9 \ge 9 \gt 0$ so the domain is all real numbers.

Comment: @JohnDouma I don't understand what you said, basically I need to show my teacher why Its $\mathbb{R}$ mathimaticly

Comment: That is a mathematical explanation. How would you show, mathematically,  that the domain of the function $g(x) = x$ is all of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @JohnDouma It is $\mathbb{R}$ because it doesn't have any $x$ in its denominator

Comment: Yes. So if it does have a denominator you must eliminate values that make it $0$. But if you reason, as above, you can show that for all $x$ the denominator is not $0$ and moreover, the value under the radical sign is not negative. Does that make sense?

Comment: Basically $x^2 > 9$ is true for all $x$ so the domain is all reals

Comment: @Dylan I don't think $0^2 > 9$.

Comment: @JohnDouma Typo! $x^2 > -9$. You know what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+9}}$$

Only $\sqrt{x^2+9}=0$ could be a problem for your domain. But as $x^2+9>0$ (sum of two squares), this cannot happen. Hence, the domain of $f$ is $R$.

If you also need to find the map of your function:
First of all we evaluate the derivative of $f(x)$

$$f'(x)=\frac{1\cdot\sqrt{x^2+9}-x\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+9}}}{(x^2+9)}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+9}-\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+9}}}{(x^2+9)}=\frac{\frac{(x^2+9)-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+9}}}{(x^2+9)}=\frac{9}{\sqrt{x^2+9}(x^2+9)}$$

As $9>0$, $(x^2+9)>0$ and $\sqrt{x^2+9}>0$, we can conclude that the function is strictly monotonic for all $x \in R$.

Now we need to evaluate the limits of $f(x)$ for $x \to \pm \infty$

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+9}}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x}{|x|\sqrt{1+\frac{9}{x^2}}}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x}{x\sqrt{1+\frac{9}{x^2}}}=1$$

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+9}}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x}{|x|\sqrt{1+\frac{9}{x^2}}}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x}{-x\sqrt{1+\frac{9}{x^2}}}=-1$$

Hence, we conclude the function maps from $R \to (-1,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you want $f(x)$ as a real valued function, and you are right. The domain is $\mathbb{R}$ since $x^2+9> 0 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, so $\sqrt{x^2+9}$ is a real number and not null for all real $x$ .